# Troubles compiling a program from source

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Visual Studio Code from the source(which comes in tar.gz archive) for Ubuntu 18.14 (architecture armhf). But there are no readme, configure, or even configure.ac. How can i compile and install it?

I downloaded it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 0):

You need to just extract the *tar.gz*

```
$tar xzf <archive>
$cd <extracted directory>
$./code
```

Comment: I extracted it already, and that's what i get after executing $./code : bash: ./code: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Can you show the output of what file it is using `file code`

Comment: code: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

Comment: you should check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error)