# How do I resolve an error when attempting the "opam init" command?

Tags: command-line

Here is the command:

```
    opam init
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    bash: /use/local/bin/opam: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Are there any suggestions on what we should try?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to execute a program that might not be a valid Linux binary; a quick search for this error online will return many sites explaining how to solve it, like these:

- [bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error)
- https://superuser.com/questions/800019/unable-to-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error
- https://appuals.com/fix-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error-ubuntu/

Check if the program you're trying to execute is compatible with your Linux kernel version, like these sites I linked suggest.

However, before actually doing this, I'd try changing that path to `/usr/local/bin/opam`, it also looks like you might have a typo in there  (usually in Linux that folder is called `usr`, not `use`).

Comment: Thank you. I got a newer version of opam and it now worked. However, the next command is now not working (because it expected the older version of opam). Any ideas for me this time? Command is: <make build-deps> and error is <Makefile:25: *** Unexpected opam version (found: 2.1.0~alpha, expected: 2.0.*). Stop.>.

Comment: Even though I know nothing about this program, the error is clear: the new version is not compatible. I'd try uninstalling it (to make sure that no conflicts will arise), then install it again, paying attention to the opam version and the system you're installing it onto.

Here are some links; you can find more by searching online:
- Uninstalling opam: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/1.1/Advanced_Install.html#Uninstalling-OPAM
- About this error: https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/9uml4u/unexpected_opam_version_issue/
- A (possible) solution: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/263