# Remove cmake from Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: software-uninstall, cmake

I needed updating my *cmake* program on Ubuntu 22.04.3 version *amd64*, but wrongly downloaded the *aarch64* version of cmake using this method (https://www.golinuxcloud.com/install-cmake-on-ubuntu/#Method-2_Install_From_Binary_File) to override the existing *cmake*. Not successful though.
Now when I type *cmake --version* on Terminal, unlike before, it responses: *bash: /usr/local/bin/cmake: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error*

How to remove cmake from my machine, now?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you downloaded the binary for the wrong platform (you're running Amd64, but downloaded for Arm64 (Aarch64).

You should then first clean up the wrong files: (here assuming version 3.27.7)

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/cmake-3.27.7-linux-aarch64
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake
```

And now, you can follow the guide again, this time installing the correct file:

```
wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.27.7/cmake-3.27.7-linux-x86_64.sh
```

And then proceed through the guide...